# Como separa em duas colunas no pandas com \n

Tags: python

```
import pandas as pd

test = pd.read_csv("1.csv")

df = pd.DataFrame(test)

print(df.head())


new = df["Nome"].str.split("\n", n=-1)


df["PT"] = new[0]
df["EN"] = new[1]

df.drop(columns=["Nome"], inplace=True)


print(df.head())
```

O arquivo "1.csv" esta:

```
,Nome,Valor
0,['Banimenton\nBanishment'],"['R$ 0,49']"
1,['Anjos de Batalha de Tyr\nBattle Angels of Tyr'],"['R$ 2,22']"
2,"[""Fogo-fátuo Atrativo\nBeckoning Will-o'-Wisp""]","['R$ 94,75']"
3,"[""Hipogrifo Abençoado // Benção de Tyr\nBlessed Hippogriff // Tyr's Blessing""]","['R$ 169,75']"
4,['Contrabandear Gado\nContraband Livestock'],"['R$ 12,25']"
5,['Dragão de Cristal // Roubar o Tesouro\nCrystal Dragon // Rob the Hoard'],"['R$ 0,43']"
6,['Fazer um Acordo\nCut a Deal'],"['R$ 0,24']"
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Onde está `new = df["Nome"].str.split("\n", n=-1)` faça `df = df.join(df["Nome"].str.strip("'\"[]").str.split(r'\\n', expand=True))`. Remova as linhas `df["PT"] = new[0]` e `df["EN"] = new[1]`. Adiciona a linha `df.rename(columns={0:"PT", 1:"EN"}, inplace=True)`

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente, vc teria a explicação do porque do .join para funcionar?

Comment: Para juntar o DataFrame gerado por `split(r'\\n', expand=True)` ao DF original. O argumento `True` passado no parâmetro `expand` faz com que o método `split()` gere um DataFrame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ao ler o arquivo CSV, as colunas Nome e Valor serão do tipo objeto e cada célula do tipo string.

Tendo o exemplo de arquivo do post, a solução mais simples seria:

```
df["PT"] = df["Nome"].apply(lambda x: x[2:-2].split("\\n")[0])
df["EN"] = df["Nome"].apply(lambda x: x[2:-2].split("\\n")[1])
```

Repare que `x[2:-2]` remove `['` do inicio e `']` do fim.

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção, no entanto, está me retornando IndexError: list index out of range.

Comment: Usando "[0]" funciona df["PT"] = df["Nome"].apply(lambda x: x[2:-2].split("\\n")[0]), agora, "[1]"nao localiza.

Comment: Usando df["EN"] = df["Nome"].apply(lambda x: x[2:-2].split("\\n")[1:2]) funciona, no entanto, não remove as [' do inicio e '] do fim.

Comment: Com a base de teste que vc enviou funciona para mim. Eu li o arquivo com `pd.read_csv('1.csv', usecols=["Nome", "Valor"]` mas não acredito que seja isso.

Comment: Colei a imagem de como o arquivo "1.csv" está se ajuda.